# How to get all the value of same class by jQuery, and insert into an array and loop count is not correct in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

This is my form

```
<?php  
        $sql15 = "select * from reviewed_title";
        $query15 = sqlsrv_query( $link, $sql15);
        $count = 1;
        while( $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query15, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) { ?>
        <div class = "title_body">
         <div class = "title_top">
          <div class="form-group">
           <h3><?php 
            $title_id = $row['id'];
            echo $count .".  ".$row['title']; 
            ?>
           </h3>
         </div>
        </div>
        <?php
        $sql16 = "select * from item_reviewed WHERE title_id = $title_id";
                        $count2=1;
         $query16 = sqlsrv_query( $link, $sql16);
         $query17 = sqlsrv_query($link, $sql16, array(), array( "Scrollable" => SQLSRV_CURSOR_KEYSET ));
         $row_num = sqlsrv_num_rows($query17);
            //$row_num = 5;
         while( $row2 = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $query16, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC) ) { ?>    
        <div class = "title_bottom"
        <?php if($row_num != $count2){?> style="border-bottom: 1px solid #000000;" <?php }?> >
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="hidden" name="item_reviewed_id" value="<?php echo $row2['id'];?>"  class="item_reviewed_id">
                <div class = "title_bottom_left">
                    <h6> <?php echo $count.".".$count2 .".  ".$row2['items']; 
                                ?></h6>
                </div>
                <div class= "title_bottom_center">
                <label class="col-sm-2 label2" for="email">Y,N,N/A:</label>
                                        <!--<select name="action" class="select <select_<?php echo $row2['id'];?>" id="select_<?php echo $count."".$count2;?>">-->
                                        <select name="action" class="select" >
                                          <option value="">Select</option>
                                        <option value="yes">Yes</option>        
                                      </select>
                                  </div>
                <div class ="title_bottom_right">
                <label class="col-sm-2 label3" for="email">Comment:</label>
                    <!--<textarea name="comment" class="form-control comment commentttt comment_<?php echo $row2['id'];?>>"  <id="comment_<?php echo $count."".$count2;?>"   placeholder="Comment"></textarea>-->
                    <textarea name="comment" class="form-control comment commentttt"    placeholder="Comment"></textarea>
                                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php $count2++;}?>
                </div>
            <?php  $count++; }?>
```

Here I get 33 input fields, 33 select fields and 33 hidden fields.From table item_reviewed here i get 33 row. My jQuery code is ..

```
var ittem_id = new Array();
    var j = 1;
    $(".item_reviewed_id" ).each(function( i ) {
        ittem_id[j] = $(this).val();
        j++;
        });
        alert(j);
```

Here I get 1552 values. How i can get 33 values in jQuery ?

Comment: try `console.log($(".item_reviewed_id" ).length);`, and share the output here

Comment: I use var ittem_id = console.log($(".item_reviewed_id" ).length);alert( ittem_id);...There show an error. Which is "TypeError: can't convert ittem_id to string." and value get 1551.

Answer (score 0):

if you ve 1552 item and that loop output only 33 rows you must ve some other elements with class .item_reviewed_id in your page.
Use 2 classes to be sure you re selecting the right elements. JQuery [map](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) could be a very easy way to map your elements values

```
<input type="hidden" name="item_reviewed_id" value="<?php echo $row2['id'];?>"  class="item_reviewed_id thisclass">

var ittem_id = $('.item_reviewed_id.thisclass').map(function(){
     return $(this).val();
});

console.log(ittem_id); //this will be an array with your values!
```

Comment: I use this    $('.item_reviewed_id.thisclass').map(function(){
             ittem_id = $(this).val();
                 });
     alert(ittem_id);  and get the alert 33.. but i need 1 to 33 in an array.

Comment: How ? Please tell me . I stuck here for 2 hours.